Always redirected to backend page from frontend whenevr i add sitefinity after the port from frontend url
I am always redirected to backend page whenever i add sitefinity after the port like this https://localhost:7191/sitefinity
How to change this behavior i dont want the user to be redirected to backend page.
This is my launchSettings file.
{
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5141"
    },
    //https is working
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7191;http://localhost:5141"
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "https://+:443;http://+:80"
      },
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "useSSL": true
    }
  },
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:14053",
      "sslPort": 44342
    }
  }
}

What i tried is below-
In the Security section, advanced via UI dashboard. I unticked Allow external role providers.
Ticked on Authenticate on frontend login page.
Multisite- unrestricted.
Also i tried to change the port from 44381 to 7191 in global.acs.cs
here string host = "https://localhost:44381";
This behavior is pertinent also in production in sitefinity 15.1.
Any thoughts on that is appreciated. thanks!

could you share your Sitefinity configurations  which is in App_Data/Sitefinity/Configuration/ location. check your Global.asax.cs file if the port is updated or not. you could try to set the custom routs  endpoints.MapGet("/sitefinity", async context =>             {                 context.Response.Redirect("/home"); // or another route you prefer             });
